# Apache RewriteRule of multiple variables in query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to figure out how to write a new rewrite rule but I am struggling badly. We are removing the world-wide (WW) site from domain.com and want to forward any old links to the country selector. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
# if any user goes to this URL
www.domain.com/products/folder1/folder2/index?sku=123&var2=abc&isocountrycode=ww

# forward them to this URL
www.domain.com/choose/country_selection?ref_url=/products/folder1/folder2/index.cfm?sku=123&var2=abc

# my attempt that does not work
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^(.*)isocountrycode=ww(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$      /choose/country_selection.cfm?ref_url=$1?%1%2 [L,R=302]
```

I have been using this website to test my code http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. Helicontech APE requires the second ? to be escaped with a backslash...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+&)?isocountrycode=ww&(.+)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /choose/country_selection.cfm?ref_url=/$1\?%1%2? [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^((.+)&)?isocountrycode=ww$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /choose/country_selection.cfm?ref_url=/$1\?%2? [NC,R=301,L]
```